# Incrementing Python loop counter inside the loop without IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, loops, increment

I am trying to create this function as described in docstring but either I get just 1st doctest passed or fail with IndexError: list index out of range. I feel this current approach will work if somehow I can increment the loop counter again inside the loop without falling off range. I tried

```
def menu_is_boring(meals):
"""Given a list of meals served over some period of time, return True if the
same meal has ever been served two days in a row, and False otherwise.

>>> menu_is_boring(['Egg', 'Spam'])
False
>>> menu_is_boring(['Spam', 'Eggs', 'Spam', 'Spam', 'Bacon', 'Spam'])
True

"""
for i in range(len(meals)):
    x = (meals[i] == meals[i+1]) and (meals[i] == meals[i+2])
return x
```

To solve the Index error I tried using while loop but that fails with syntax error:

```
for i in range(len(meals)):
    x = (meals[i] == meals[(while i<len(meals): i+=1 )]) and (meals[i] == meals[while i<len(meals):i+=2])
```

Will a nested loop somehow work or am I over complicating this?

P.S. There is solution available to the problem but I am trying to see what is wront with my approach or get a hint , instead of jumping to the solution directly. This my 1st question so please excuse me if it is not following all the guidelines.

Comment: You can't increment `i` with `i+=1` and use it as an index. That's what's causing the syntax error. The index error is because you are trying to access `meals[i+2]`. The maximum value of `i` is the last index of `meals` so to avoid the index error you can only iterate up to `range(len(meals)-2)`

Comment: The logical error in your code is that each time through the loop, you *replace* your assessment of whether the menu is boring *with the result from the most recent comparison*; but as soon as you have found the menu to be boring, it logically cannot become interesting again.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the last meal:

```
def menu_is_boring(meals):
    last = None
    for meal in meals:
        if meal == last:
            return True
        last = meal
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're checking for 3 days in a row with `x = (meals[i] == meals[i+1]) and (meals[i] == meals[i+2])`. Also, the `IndexError` is caused by the fact that you're trying to access the `n+1th` and `n+2th` elements of a list with `n` elements. To avoid that, you should run the loop till `n-1` or `n-2` as necessary.

So all you have to do is:

```
for i in range(len(meals)-1):  # Run the loop till n-1
    x = meals[i] == meals[i+1] # Check for nth and n+1th meal to be same
return x
```

Having said that, this section will not solve your problem, and will always return the value for the last meal pair, since `x` is getting overwritten on every iteration of the loop. To solve that, you can return a `True` as soon as you find a repetition.

```
def menu_is_boring(meals):
    for i in range(len(meals)-1):
        if meals[i] == meals[i+1]:
            return True
    return False
```

You can test it by calling the function and printing its return value.

```
print (menu_is_boring(['Spam', 'Eggs', 'Spam', 'Spam', 'Bacon', 'Spam']))
```